# How to keep a concrete wall cool?

Tags: walls, heat

I'm a student renting a room on the 2nd floor of a small apartment. When i got back from the holidays i found out our next door neighbors extended their house and built a shed. The roof of their extended house+shed is now almost touching the outer wall of my rented room. Now, that roof is probably reflecting the heat to my wall and is heating up the place.

Anyway i could cool down this wall in a cheap way? I really like this room as its convenient and it fits right into my budget.

Comment: Could you ask your landlord to paint the wall white?

Comment: You are speculating about an effect that will almost certainly be marginal and may even be negligible.  An elderly neighbor on a nearby street told me that when his next door neighbor on a street of 2500 to 3500 sq ft fancy houses got a shiny standing seam metal roof it reflected sunlight on his house and increased the heat load. I didn't respond. Some people think the whole world should agree with them and cater to their wishes. Welcome to the world of 7 bn people headed to 9 bn or 12 bn.

Comment: waft black spray point onto the shiny roof to kill reelections? or use lattice/vines or other blockers.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly buy some insulation material from your local hardware or building supply store.

The cheapest would be to buy fiberglass insulation, but I would recommend against this, because it can be bad for your lungs if not installed properly.

The quickest and easiest would be to get some rigid foam board insulation and put it up against the wall.  With this you could probably wallpaper over it, or possibly even paint some types.

Be sure to check the R-Value on the insulation that you want to use.  The higher the R-Value, the better insulation that you will get.

I know that it doesn't seem like you will get a lot of benefit from some foam board, but you would be surprised.

[Home Depot - All Insulation](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Building-Materials-Insulation/N-5yc1vZasbs?redirect=true&NCNI-5&searchRedirect=insulation&semanticToken=20041%20%20%20%3E%20%20%20%20st%3A%7Binsulation%7D%3Ast%20%20cn%3A%7B0%3A0%7D%20%20insulation%20%7Bredirect%7D)

[Home Depot - Rigid Insulation](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Building-Materials-Insulation-Rigid-Insulation/N-5yc1vZbaxx)

From a cost perpective, you aren't looking at anything outrageous either.

Let's assume your wall is 8 feet tall (for simplicity)
and that it's 24 feet long.  (That's a pretty decent sized wall for a room)

You will need 6 - 4x8 pieces of Rigid Insulation Board.
at ~$20 / sheet for the 1" stuff, that's $120 (US)
at ~$37 / sheet for the 2" stuff, that's $220 (US)

If you do install the foam board, be sure to get some foam sealer (like Great Stuff) and put that in between the cracks.  Small gaps in the foam board can make a surprisingly big difference.

The next step would be putting sheetrock or really inexpensive plywood / fiber board over it.

Good Luck and let us know how it works out!

Comment: The new roof “comes over and almost touches your wall”? Aren’t there any property lines where you live? Call the local Building Code Department and find out if they got a permit and why they can build so close to your apartment. I just did that on a piece of property I own, and the Building Codes Department made them tear it down.